# Laurent series expansion with multiple taylor expansions

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

Find the laurent series expansion for the following function: $$f(z)=\frac{e^z}{z^3-z^4}$$

---

What I've done is:

\begin{align}
f(z) & = \frac{e^z}{z^3-z^4}  \\
 & = \frac{e^z}{z^3(1-z)} \\
 & = \frac{e^z}{z^3} .\frac{1}{1-z} \\
 & = \frac{e^z}{z^3}\Big(1+z+z^2+\dots\Big) \\
 & = e^z\Big(\frac{1}{z^3}+\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{1}{z}+1+z+z^2+\dots\Big) \\
 & = \Big(1+z+\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^3}{6}+\frac{z^4}{24}+\frac{z^5}{60}+\dots \Big)\Big(\frac{1}{z^3}+\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{1}{z}+1+z+z^2+\dots\Big) \\
 \end{align}

Am I supposed to multiply this out? Surely there's a better way?

Comment: Do you mean the Laurent series expansion *centered at* $0$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I guess so yeah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it. First of all, I would compute the Taylor expansion of $\dfrac{e^z}{1-z}$:\begin{align}\frac{e^z}{1-z}&=\left(1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots\right)\left(1+z+z^2+z^3+\cdots\right)\\&=1+2z+\frac52z^2+\cdots+\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k!}\right)z^n+\cdots\end{align}And then\begin{align}\frac{e^z}{z^3-z^4}&=\frac1{z^3}\cdot\frac{e^z}{1-z}\\&=\frac1{z^3}\left(1+2z+\frac52z^2+\cdots+\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k!}\right)z^n+\cdots\right)\\&=\frac1{z^3}+\frac2{z^2}+\frac5{2z}+\cdots+\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n+3}\frac1{k!}\right)z^n+\cdots\end{align}